# Facebook PHP API Questions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for the Facebook API calls to obtain the following information (Im using the facebook php api)

- posts per hour
- likes
- comments
- shares
- re-shares by friends
- number of friends that the friend who re-shared your post has
- clicks on links within post

I tried reading the api documents ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)) but they don't really tell me what im looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the Facebook API-docs already?

Comment: Well you are looking for specific types of stories. You should take a look at the [`/feed` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed). Another great tool that Facebook supplies us with is the [Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) - use it to feel your way around the API and get to know what type of data you are working with. In some cases, you'll have to manually filter the data in order to get to the specifics that you require.

Comment: the api explorer is precisely what i need. can you make that answer and ill accept it as the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the information you are after can't be retrieved directly from the API. You'll have to filter some of the data that is returned. Most of the things you are referring to are types of  stories in a users feed. So the [`/feed` enpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed) would be a great place to start looking.

Facebook has a great took called the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). You can easily use it to navigate you're way around the API and see just what it has to offer without having to write code at all.